# Subi uma aplicação web em C# Asp net e está ocorrendo o seguinte

Tags: c#, asp

```
Server Error in '/sistemas/manutencao' Application.
________________________________________
Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=314055 for more information.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=314055 for more information.

Source Error:

[No relevant source lines]

Source File: c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\sistemas_manutencao\07cccae9\84f1a3f\App_Web_vea1b2xt.6.cs    Line: 0

Stack Trace:

[ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. 
    Client IP: 152.237.208.182
    Port: 5170
    Referer: http://sscomp.com.br/sistemas/manutencao/WebFormConsultaProd.aspx
    Path: /sistemas/manutencao/WebFormConsultaProd.aspx
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36
    ViewState: /wEPDwUKMTgxNjM4NTg3NA9kFgICAw9kFggCFQ8PFgIeBFRleHQFATFkZAIfDw8WAh4ISW1hZ2VVcmwFHVBST0RVVE9TL0lNUFJFU1NPUkEgQ0FUQU8ucG5nZGQCPQ8PFgIfAAVJRGVzZW52b2x2ZW1vcyBzZXUgYXBsaWNhdGl2byBkZSBlbWlzc8OjbyBkZSBjYXJ0w6NvIC0gWmFwOiAoMzEpOTg3MzMtODY4MmRkAj8PPCsAEQMADxYEHgtfIURhdGFCb3VuZGceC18hSXRlbUNvdW50AgVkARAWAQIBFgE8KwAFAQAWAh4KSGVhZGVyVGV4dAULRGVzY3Jpw6fDo28WAWYMFCsAABYCZg9kFg4CAQ9kFgpmDw8WAh8ABQExZGQCAQ8PFgIfAAUiSW1wcmVzc29yYSBkZSBjdXBvbiBmaXNjYWwgQkVNQVRFQ2RkAgIPDxYCHwAFBzIwMDAsMDBkZAIDDw8WAh8ABQRSRUFMZGQCBg9kFgICAQ8PFgIeD0NvbW1hbmRBcmd1bWVudAUBMWRkAgIPZBYKZg8PFgIfAAUBMmRkAgEPDxYCHwAFMkltcHJlc3NvcmEgdCYjMjMzO3JtaWNhIFpUMjMwIFpFQlJBIHVzYixzZXJpYWwgMjMwZGQCAg8PFgIfAAUHNTMyMCwwMGRkAgMPDxYCHwAFBFJFQUxkZAIGD2QW...]

[HttpException (0x80004005): Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=314055 for more information.]
   System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError) +116
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString, Purpose purpose) +425
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter2.Deserialize(String serializedState, Purpose purpose) +13
   System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter2 formatter, String serializedState, Purpose purpose) +40
   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +248
   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() +251
   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState() +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +6569
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +245
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +72
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +22
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +58
   ASP.webformconsultaprod_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\sistemas_manutencao\07cccae9\84f1a3f\App_Web_vea1b2xt.6.cs:0
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +188
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +71

________________________________________
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3650.0
```